# Row value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table that is having 2 duplicate rows (total of 3 rows), so I used the code below to get the duplicate value in the column

```
SELECT CustNo, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM Rental
GROUP BY CustNo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

So once I get the repeated value, I need to get the CustNo derived as duplicate from the customer table. How do I go about taking this value and using it in the select statment all in the same query.
I also have the select statement prepared like this.

```
Select *  from Customer where  CustNo = 'T0002';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from Customer 
where CustNo IN
(
  SELECT CustNo
  FROM Rental
  GROUP BY CustNo
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: That's it! simple and easy. :) tks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT CustNo, COUNT(*) TotalCount
      FROM Rental
      GROUP BY CustNo
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) cc JOIN
     Customer c
     on cc.CustNo = c.CustNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select C.*  from Customer C RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT CustNo
FROM Rental
GROUP BY CustNo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) D
ON C.CustNo = D.CustNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

With tblDups as(
select CustNo,count(CustNo) as TotalCount from a_rental
Group by CustNo
Having count(CustNo) >1)

select b.* from a_rental b
inner join tblDups a on a.CustNo = b.Custno